# Diffgeo question on curves and properties of dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be a curve such that $\gamma(a)=p$ and $\gamma(b)=q$ and let $u$ be a unit vector.

A) Prove $\gamma'(t) \cdot u$ $\leq$ $\|\gamma’(t)\|$

For this one I use the properties of dot product, noting that $u=\frac{\gamma’}{\|\gamma\|}$ but I always end up just showing that the quantities are equal.

B) Use path integrals to show ($\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)) \cdot u$ $\leq$ $\int_{a}^{b} \|\gamma'(t)\| dt$

For this one I observe that $u=\frac{(q-p)}{\|(q-p)\|}$ and sloppily reach a conclusion.

C) Prove the length of gamma from $p$ to $q$ is larger than or equal to the length of the straight line between $p$ and $q$.

This one is intuitively obvious, but for the proof I observe the straight line dist is just $\|p-q\|$ and the length of gamma is the arc length. I had myself convinced I had this part the other day, but now I’m confused.

Hopefully someone can make this all more clear for me. I apologize for the terrible (lack of) formatting

Thx

Nick

Comment: You can't choose $u$, it's a given unit vector, independent from $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three hints.

A) Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle v, w \rangle|\leq \|v\| \|w\|$. What do you choose for $v$ and $w$?

B) Use the fact that for two real functions $f$ and $g$ with $f\leq g$, one has
$$
   \int_a^b f(t)\,dt \leq  \int_a^b g(t)\,dt.
$$
What $f$ and $g$ do you choose?

C) You have now proven the inequality 
$$(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\cdot u \leq \int_a^b \|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt$$ 
for every unit vector $u$. Note that the right hand side $\int_a^b \|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt$ is the length of $\gamma$. Choose an appropriate $u$ to show $\|p-q\|$ is smaller than the length of $\gamma$.

Comment: Ok, i think i see how i can use the statement from part a to prove b and c. For part b i state we know from part a that the left side of b is essentially int(gamma*u) and it follows that the inequality holds. Part c is from part b as the right side of b is arc length and then use the straight line distance of u by the ratio that defines u. But, I still don’t understand part a and to say from part a in my solution i need part a lol

Comment: For a: $\gamma'(t)\cdot u \leq |\gamma'(t)\cdot u|\leq \|\gamma'(t)\| \|u\|$.

Comment: Yeah i had that somewhere but wasn’t sure it was a valid operation. Thx

Comment: I managed to prove part a by contradiction. Does this seem right? Assume v’(t)*u>||v’(t)||. So, ||v’(t)||^2/(||v’(t)||)>||v’(t)||, as u=v/||v|| for all v, which is clearly false, so <= must be true??

Comment: You are talking about part a), I guess? The proof doesn't need contradiction. Just use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $\gamma'$ and $u$, it gives literally the inequality you need.

Comment: I see that, but how do u get know the magnitude of the dot product is greater than or equal to the original dot product. Is that a property I’m missing? My question is how u progress from the far left to the middle portion of your single line comment above

Comment: Note that the dot product is a real number. And every number $a$ is smaller than or equal to its absolute value: $a\leq |a|$. That's it! :)

Comment: Oh, duh. Thx for your help sir!